# Illegal continue statement?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have something similar to the following code:

```
_.each data, (value, type) ->
    switch type
        when "answered"
            icon = "results_answered"
            label = definitions.results.metrics.ta
        when "leftblank"
            icon = "results_lb"
            label = definitions.results.metrics.tlb
        when "standing"
            icon = "results_standing"
            label = definitions.results.metrics.cs
        when "minimum"
            icon = "results_min"
            label = definitions.results.metrics.lowest
        else
            continue

    metricLine = utilities.div("metricline")
    metricLine.grab utilities.sprite(icon, "metric_icon")
    metricLine.grab utilities.div("metriclabel", label + ":")
    metricLine.grab utilities.div("metricvalue", value)
    metricContainer.grab(metricLine)

metricContainer
```

But it throws the following error to my browser:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement

Is it possible to include a `continue` like I am trying without throwing the error?

Comment: what do you actually want to `continue` ?

Comment: `continue` is a JavaScript language feature. It probably doesn't work without a regular loop in its enclosing lexical scope.

Comment: I want to go to the next item in my loop without executing any of the code after my `continue` for the current item.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you want to continue with the next loop iteration, you want `return`, not `continue`, as what you're passing to `each` is a function.

In a comment you mentioned being familiar wih the C# `foreach` loop, hence wanting to use `continue`. The difference is that wih C#'s `foreach`, you're dealing with an actual loop construct, whereas `each` is actually calling a function for each loop iteration, so it's not (at a language level) a loop, so you can't `continue` it.

Comment: Yeah that was it, sorry I come from a C# background where `continue` apparently means something else.

Comment: Ahhhhh, that makes more sense.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Thank you! 
save me a lot of time searching for a "continue" statement alternative for angularJs

Answer (score 12):

you are not using a loop construct in your code but a closure.
you can only exit from a loop with continue. When using underscores each
function you have to exit the closure/function via return

```
#language construct
for item in items
    if some_condition
        continue

#closure construct
_.each data, (item) ->
    if some_condition
        return
```