# Discord.js - Continue loop for next users from Reaction.users.fetch().each((user) => {...});

Tags: javascript, discord.js, dom-events, bots, javascript-objects

Heres a code snippet under `client.on('ready', async() => {...});`:

```
this.MyServer = await client.guilds.fetch('MyServer ID here').catch(error => { console.log(error) });
this.MyRole = await this.Server.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name == `MyRole name here`);
this.MyChannel = await client.channels.fetch('MyChannel ID here').catch(error => { console.log(error) });
this.MyMessage = await this.RoleChannel.messages.fetch('MyMessage ID here').catch(error => { console.log(error) });
this.MyEmojiReaction = await this.MyMessage.reactions.cache.get('MyEmoji ID here');
this.ReactingUsers = await this.MyEmojiReaction.users.fetch();

this.ReactingUsers.each(async (user) => {
 if (!this.MyServer.members.cache.get(user.id)) return;
 if (!user.bot) {
  try {
   const member = await this.MyMessage.guild.members.fetch(user.id);
   member.roles.add(this.MyRole);
  } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
   return;
  }
 }
});
```

As the bot starts, it should check for the reaction, `this.MyEmojiReaction` in the message, `this.MyMessage` in the channel, `this.MyChannel`, and add the reacting users stored in `this.ReactingUsers` to the role, `this.MyRole`. It is working mostly fine except one problem.

The first line `if (!this.MyServer.members.cache.get(user.id)) return;` in `this.ReactingMembers.each(async (user) => {..}`is responsible to return from the function if the user from `this.ReactingMembers` is not present in `this.MyServer` and it does but as it returns, the function never executes for the next users in `this.ReactingMembers`, maybe because it returns from the entire loop. I want to continue the loop for the next users.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correctly, you should use [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue).

It will instead go to the next iteration, and the next User in the array.

In your case, instead of this:

```js
if (!this.MyServer.members.cache.get(user.id)) return;
```

You should do it like this:

```js
if (!this.MyServer.members.cache.has(user.id))  continue;
```

Comment: if (!this.Server.members.cache.get(user.id)) continue;
                                                 ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement: no surrounding iteration statement

Comment: It looks like a loop but in reality it is a closure function as mentioned in two answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14838222/13553934).

Comment: You can change it to a for of loop can’t you?

Comment: I am new to JS, but I believe I can do it after some research. Thank you

Comment: Well if it helped, please checkmark this question to mark it as correct

Comment: please checkmark this *answer* to mark it as correct